# Compilation warning with gfortran on assignment of LOGICAL(C_BOOL) variable

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using a program that uses mixed language C and Fortran, like in the following example.

```
PROGRAM boolean
   USE ISO_C_BINDING
   IMPLICIT NONE
   LOGICAL (KIND = C_BOOL) :: cbool
   INTEGER :: i, j
   i = 1
   j = 2
   cbool = i /= j
   WRITE(*,*) cbool
END PROGRAM boolean
```

I compile it on Windows 10 with gfortran 10 from MSYS2-MINGW64 distribution using the following command:

```
gfortran boolean.f90 -o boolean -Wall
```

And I get the following warning message:

```
boolean.f90:8:11:

    8 |    cbool = i /= j
      |           1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from LOGICAL(4) to LOGICAL(1) at (1) [-Wconversion]
```

I can solve this warning by changing to:

```
 cbool = LOGICAL(i /= j,1)
```

I understand that this is because a different storage size is used by C_BOOL and the default logical in gfortran.

The questions: under what circumstances is it possible for the value to change as the warning says? What is the best way to remove this warning message, appart from using the LOGICAL intrinsic function?

Comment: What an annoying warning! I can't see how it can ever cause any problems, and I have to admit that use of the Logical type conversion function is the only simple way I can think of to get rid of it. But a comment as there might be something I have overlooked.

Comment: Adding the conversion function is exactly what I did in my code. I do not see why looking for anything apart from that, it is the right thing to do.

Comment: If you do not want to see the warning, then do not ask gfortran to produce it.  You can either remove the `-Wall` option or add the `-Wno-conversion` option after `-Wall`.  The correct fix is `cbool = logical(i /= j, C_BOOL)`.

Comment: My preferred form is cbool = logical(i /= j, Kind( cbool ) ) which works in the (probably very unlikely) event you change the kind of cbool

Comment: @IanBush, I wrote `logical( i /= j , C_BOOL)`.  `C_BOOL` is the kind type parameter from the `ISO_C_BINDING` module.  It is unlikely a user can change `C_BOOL`, and `C_BOOL` was the kind type parameter used in the declaration of the variable `cbool`.

Comment: Yes. I saw that. I wrote an expression which will not generate a warning whatever the kind of cbool. You are assuming cbool has kind C_BOOL. My expression avoids that assumption.

Comment: Fortran is very strict with anything, including kind types. This is a good thing, and the compiler is doing well to warn you (although I admit in this particular case it doesn't make much sense to even have booleans of different kinds). Better strict than "loose", as is the case in most languages. So `logical(1/=j,kind=c_bool)` is the solution (`kind=c_bool` instead of `c_bool` is required by some compilers following the `F` standard). I would never suppress conversion warnings with `Wno-conversion` though.

Comment: This is, IMHO, a bug in gfortran. I filed https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96319